# PHP header location redirect causing 500 Internal Server error

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, header, server-error

I keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error when the script below reaches the header`('location:php_email_thankyou.php')`.

I'm not sure what is causing this, as I can place the header expression before or after the if statements and it works fine. In firebug it mentions a GET request for the `php_email_thankyou.php` page not sure if that means anything...

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');   
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);    

include('php/cl/cl_val.php');  
$val = new Validate;  
$print_errors = false;  

if (isset($_POST['email(email)'])){  
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']))  
    {  
        $validation = $val->clean($_POST);  
        if (isset($validation['send']))   
        {  
            header('location:php_email_thankyou.php');  
            exit();  
        }  
        else   
        {  
            print json_encode($validation);  
            exit();  
        }  
    }   
    else   
    {  
        $validation = $val->clean($_POST);  
    }  
}  

?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Are you sure it's not the target file causing the server error?

Comment: Plus, can you look into your server's error logs? They will contain an explanation why the 500 happened.

Comment: Try to manually type in the url of the php_email_thankyou.php into the address bar and browse to it to see if you can actually go to that page without any errors. If by manually browsing to it you're still getting 500 error, then it means the error comes from the thank you page, not from the redirect header.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/1.1 requires the location used to be an abolute path, not relative. Try this;

```
header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/php_email_thankyou.php');
```

Comment: That's now how you think, you can specify the relative path too.

Comment: Browsers tend to support relative redirects, but the RFC clearly requires an absolute URI, as MatW stated: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30 So don't be surprised if relative paths in the Location header fail to work with certain user agents.  "It works in firefox" doesn't mean it's right.

Comment: Hey thanks everyone for your answers. 

The target file is O.K, I can navigate to it fine.

I dont think it is an absolute/relative issue, as when I place the header redirect in the first line or even just before the DOCTYPE declaration it works fine as is, so I appreciate it may not be the technically correct syntax, but it still works.

I was thinking maybe its an ajax issue? Perhaps the page is still loading will the ajax is ticking over.

Comment: @globa: check the server's error log. There'll be more details on WHAT caused the 500 there. The 500 output you see in the browser is deliberately minimalized and is utterly useless for any form of debugging.